# Error "grub-efi-amd64-signed" when installing Linux

Tags: linux, software-installation, partition, grub2, lubuntu

I'm trying to install Lubuntu, first with dual boot with windows, then alone, and I'm not able to install it because I have always the same error when the process are going to create GRUB.

This is the error, and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

> The 'grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/.
>   Without enter code here`the GRUB boot loader, the installed system
>   will not boot

When I have tried to install it twice alone, I have created this partitions:

```
/dev/sda1 ext4 /

/dev/sda2 efi

/dev/sda3 ext4 /home

/dev/sda4 ext4 /var

/dev/sda5 swap
```

The difference between installations is that the first time I have selected /dev/sda2 the place where create GRUB and the second time I have selected /dev/sda. And I have get it the same error explained above.

I'm trying to do the installations through USB booteable

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your ESP partition should be mounted at `/boot/efi`, I think. Your partition configuration listing suggests you may be creating the ESP partition (`/dev/sda2`) but leaving it unmounted.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to try it again. I tell you something in a while.